# Equation related to the curve $x^4+3kx^3+6x^2+5$

Tags: calculus

The sum of all the integral value(s) of 'k' so that the curve $x^4+3kx^3+6x^2+5$ is not situated below any of its tangent line is

(A) 5

(B) 2

(C) 0

(D) -2

I have no idea of how to proceed this question

Comment: For example, $y=x^2$ has the property being referred to in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curve $y=x^4 + 3 k x^3 + 6 x^2 + 5$ is concave up if $y''>0$ that is

$$6 \left(2x^2+3 k x+2\right)>0 ;\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$
this happens when the discriminant $(9 k^2-16)$ is negative, that is when $-\frac{4}{3}<k<\frac{4}{3}$ and the sum of the integer values in this interval is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

This property is called concave up, so we just solve for $f''(x)>0$ for all $x$ where $f(x)$ is the given curve.